# ORC: Partition by groups of column values

Tags: java, apache-spark, orc

I've written a simple Java maven application that depends on spark-hive_2.11 in order to convert JSON to ORC.

My current application partitions by year, month and day and then writes each partition out as an ORC file, however I now need to have it partition by year, month, day and a grouping of account numbers.

NOTE: I'm not working with HDFS, Hive, Pig, etc.  Just a simple Java application that uses a Spark Session to organize and then convert JSON records to ORC files.

As an example (for sake of simplicity assume just yearly partition instead of year, month and day), if I had the following data:

```
Year    Account
2009    Acct1
2009    Acct2
2009    Acct3
2009    Acct4
2009    Acct5
2009    Acct1
2009    Acct2
2009    Acct3
```

And I wanted to partition by year and groups of accounts (`grouping 1: { Acct1, Acct2 }` and `grouping 2: { Acct3, Acct4, Acct5 }`), I would want ORC partitions that represent:

Partition 1:

```
Year    Account
2009    Acct1
2009    Acct2
2009    Acct1
2009    Acct2
```

Partition 2:

```
Year    Account
2009    Acct3
2009    Acct4
2009    Acct5
2009    Acct3
```

Below is my current code:

```
sparkSession.read()
    .json("jsonFile.json")
    .toDF()
    .repartition(1)
    .write()
    .options(sparkOptions)
    .partitionBy("year","month","day")
    .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
    .orc("orcDir");
```

Is there a way, in my above code, to create a grouping of column values to use as a partition key in addition to the year,month,day columns?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't test this but you can also try something like below:

```
val acctGroup = List(List("Acct1","Acct2"),List("Acct3","Acct4","Acct5"))

for {account <- acctGroup} 
    df.where($"account".isin(account: _*)).select("*").show()

+----+-------+
|Year|Account|
+----+-------+
|2009|  Acct1|
|2009|  Acct2|
|2009|  Acct1|
|2009|  Acct2|
+----+-------+      

+----+-------+
|Year|Account|
+----+-------+
|2009|  Acct3|
|2009|  Acct4|
|2009|  Acct5|
|2009|  Acct3|
+----+-------+
```

You can try saving the csv for each group:

```
for {account <- acctGroup} 
    df.where($"account".isin(account: _*)).select("*").write.format(......)
```

Comment: I'll give that a shot.   Thanks!

Comment: Could you modify your answer to be able to account for account numbers that are NOT in the list of accounts?  So, Acct1 and Acct2 in one partition, Acct3, Acct4 and Acct5 in another partition and everything else in one final partition?

Comment: Try `df.where(not($"account".isin(acctGroup.flatten: _*))).show()`. Just for the final partition